# Declaring all CSS background properties in one line — especially background-size

Tags: html, css, safari

So here's my code:

```
background: url(images/my-image.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
```

This works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari for some reason?

I used to declare my `background-size` on it's own line but as I understand it it should be possible to declare all properties in one line using a forward slash?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the `background-size` property needs to be prefixed with `-webkit-` and can not be used within shorthand declaration in Safari. So leaf of `/ cover` and set that separately like `-webkit-background-size: cover`.

Comment: You probably do not have to leaf it of, just beneath your `background: ... ` shorthand add `-webkit-background-size: cover`, that should work.

Answer (score 39):

As one line short hand code seems do unknown for safari browsers meaning of cover:

```
background: url(images/my-image.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
```

I faced the same issue before. And the following worked for all browsers:

```
background: url(images/my-image.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;/*now this is known for the safari*/
```

Answer (score 6):

background property has following attributes.

- **`url`**`("image path")`
- **`bg-color`** e.g transparent or any color
- **`bg-img-repeat`** e.g `repeat` or `no=repeat`
- **`bg-image-postion`** vertical and horizontal e.g `center center`
- **`bg-img-size`** e.g `cover`, `contain`, `100%`, `800px`, or `200px 100px` (width and height) etc

We will write like this

```
background: url("images/my-image.png") transparent no-repeat bottom center  / cover;
background-size: cover; /*for safari we can add this sperately*/
```