# Hide white space/HTML overflow from HTML for sibling div in Router when one component is rendered?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

My app is using React Router. The way it's set up, The navbar and a section with class container is always displayed. For the homepage, a Landing component with `height: 100vh` is displayed with a background image. My issue is white space is displayed below it which causes a scrollbar. The whitespace is caused by the margin top and bottom values for the section with class .container that is always rendered (a sibling of the Landing component route).

[image]
[image]

App.js:

```
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        {/* exact prop needed to prevent all routes starting with "/" to render */}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        {/* Every page within theme except landing page has a class of container to center everything */}
        <div className="container">
          <Alert />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <CreateProfile
              exact
              path="/create-profile"
              component={CreateProfile}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

My issue is that for the landing page, a background-image is set, but the margin-top and margin-bottom values of the section with class container are causing the white space below the showcase/landing page background image and a scrollbar appears. Setting `html { overflow-y: hidden }` also works but I can't do that since it chops off content on components that do require a scrollbar.

Full code in GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/nataliecardot/devconnect).
Full CSS [here](https://github.com/nataliecardot/devconnect/blob/master/client/src/App.css).
Landing page component [here](https://github.com/nataliecardot/devconnect/blob/master/client/src/components/layout/Landing.js).
App.js/parent component with router [here](https://github.com/nataliecardot/devconnect/blob/master/client/src/App.js).

```
    /* div that is always rendered, inside Router */
    .container {
      max-width: 800px;
      /* Top/right/bottom/left. */
      margin: 6rem auto 3rem auto;  /* If I comment this line out, the white space below landing page background/showcase image and scrollbar disappear */
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 2rem;
    } 

    /* Landing page (Landing component) */
    .landing {
      /* center center is background-position, cover is background-size (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558245/declaring-all-css-background-properties-in-one-line-especially-background-size) */
      /* background-position (center center here) has a 2-value syntax: one value defines X and the other defines Y. Default value is top left or 0% 0% */
      background: url('./img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: round 2, eh? ;) Can't you just add the `.container` class as a wrapper to the respective components to prevent it from always being rendered?

Comment: Yes, that's my backup plan, but it will be tedious so hoping for a simpler solution XD

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you only have a handful components and that seems like a future-proof approach. What made me notice the problem in the first place in your other topic was your comment about the `.container` class. Whatever you add to that rule set in the future is always possibly going to affect your `Landing` component and apparently you never wanted that to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your repo and made a few changes that should help you as you develop. I'll try to be brief as possible as there's quite a bit to cover:

- When setting an element as `100%` of a parent element, the parent element needs to have a height/width specified -- unless you traverse the `html`, `body`, `#root` and **all** parent elements and set each of them as `100%`. By doing so, you'll take up the browser's viewport. In some circumstances, you'll need to use `100vh`, where the viewport may dynamically grow/shrink with additional html elements. That said, by default, HTML elements have `0px by 0px` dimensions when not defined. So, if the parent has a height or width of 0, and you set a child as 100%, it'll be 100% of 0!
- You can `dispatch` actions outside of a component. For example, you have a `loadUser()` function that needs to be executed as the app is loaded. Since this only needs to be executed once, you can move it outside of the `App`.
- You can create reusable components to tackle repetitive code. For example, you're trying to center your routes by rendering a `.container` div. However, how you have it set up, it'll always be rendered and conflict with your layout. Instead, you can move it to a `layout` component and wrap your other component/routes as needed, for example: `<Container>...</Container>`. This cleans up the routes and makes it so you can conditionally center your components (there may come a time in development when you have a route/component that you don't want centered and, with your current implementation, you'll have to fight against that parent `.container`).
- When using functional components, I like to avoid anonymous functions in the render method (habit from using class based components). That said, by default an event handler, like `onClick`, passes an `event` back to a callback function. So, `onClick={handleClick}` will pass back an `event` to the callback `handleClick`. Therefore, you don't need to create an anonymous function: `onClick={e => handleClick(e)}` as this is redundant. There will be situations will you'll need to pass back more than an `event`, then you can use an anonymous function; otherwise, it's not necessary. In addition, when using a state setter function and you're spreading out previous values, it's best to use the callback function: `setState(prevState => ({...prevState, etc }));` as this ensures that the values are current upon execution (setting `state` is asynchronous, so using outside scoped variables isn't guaranteed to have the most up-to-date values). On a side note, I like to use `useCallback` as it memoizes the callback function (not necessary, but it can help prevent potential memory leaks).
- Be sure to fix your warnings! Comment out unused code (for the time being) and/or fix them. It makes it easier for another developer to help when they don't have to fight against a long list of warnings as soon as they run your application.
- On that note, start adding tests now while you're still in the early stages. Common mistake is for developers to bypass testing and hope everything works in production. Don't. As you develop, you should be writing tests for your components. This ensures that the code you've added doesn't break the existing code-base. If you're not familiar with `jest` or `enzyme` (or some other variant), now is a great time to start learning. Trust me when I say, it's no fun spending 2-3+ months going back over your entire project writing nothing but tests (it hurts the soul)!
- Last but not least, I'd highly recommend using [css modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)! They isolate/scope the css to the component, help webpack determine code-splitting, and allow your reusable components to be passed off to another developer -- and most importantly avoids the need to have a `App.css` file that's 600+ lines long! Better yet, use [sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide) modules (they're must easier to develop with, especially when selecting `hover`, `focus` or pseudo elements -- and even selecting child elements). Even better than that, use [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to avoid using CSS stylesheets altogether. Why? CSS is a render blocking source... meaning it prevents the page from loading until all of it has been downloaded. Styled-components essentially attaches a `script` tag your `public/index.html` file -- thereby bypassing the need to download additional stylesheets.

Anyway, here's a fork of your repo with the changes above: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/devconnect-refactored

If you have any questions, or something isn't quite clear, feel free to ask. I'll do my best to help. Othwerwise, code is looking good, keep chugging along.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions, they're helpful! I will take a look at your changes.